# Dropdownlist selected value not showing while updating the form

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii2

Here i like to explain my problem

i have dropdownlist called companytype, it contains value 1+1, 1+2, 1+3, 1+4, 1+5, 1+6, 1+7

while creating form i have a select a value eg:1+4 and store, but the same while updating the value getting change as select companytype [prompt]

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'companytype')->dropDownList([ '1' => '1+1', '2' => '1+2', '3' => '1+3', '4' => '1+4', '5' => '1+5', '6' => '1+6', '7' => '1+7', ], ['prompt' => 'Select Company Type', ]) ?>
```

here i have added two images you can easily understand my question

gridview of created form
[image: gridview of created form]

updating the same form
[image: updating the same form]

updated:

mycontroller code:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {

        if(Yii::$app->user->can( 'create-company' ) ) 
        {
          $model = new Company();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {

            $model->createdat = date('Y-m-d');
            $ro = $model->relationoption;
                if($ro == 'fixed')
                {
                  $commaList = implode(', ', $model->relation);
                  $model->relation = $commaList;
                }

                $model->save();
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]); 
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }  
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ForbiddenHttpException;

        }

    }
```

controller code for update

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        if(Yii::$app->user->can('update-company'))
        {
            $model = $this->findModel($id);

            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) 
            {
                $model->updatedat = date('Y-m-d h:m:s');

                  $ro = $model->relationoption;
                  if($ro == 'fixed')
                  {
                    $commaList = implode(', ', $model->relation);
                    $model->relation = $commaList;
                  }
                  $model->save();
                  return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            }
                return $this->render('update', [
                    'model' => $model,
                ]);
            }
        else
        {
            throw new ForbiddenHttpException;
        }

    }
```

> Is there anyone to answer, pls answer me

Comment: Can you show your controller code? Have you set $model->companytype = 4 in it?

Comment: see above , i have updated my question

Comment: You have given the code for create and in your question you are asking about the update?

Comment: see above i have updated it

Answer (score 0):

I dont see $model->companytype = 4 in your update action. Can you add it to your update action and check. So your update action should look like:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        if(Yii::$app->user->can('update-company'))
        {
            $model = $this->findModel($id);
            $model->companytype = 4;

            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) 
            {
                $model->updatedat = date('Y-m-d h:m:s');

                  $ro = $model->relationoption;
                  if($ro == 'fixed')
                  {
                    $commaList = implode(', ', $model->relation);
                    $model->relation = $commaList;
                  }
                  $model->save();
                  return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            }
                return $this->render('update', [
                    'model' => $model,
                ]);
            }
        else
        {
            throw new ForbiddenHttpException;
        }

    }
```

Comment: pls understand how can i see the selected value while am updating.

Comment: there is many values from 1 to 7, how i can keep 4 alone, i need the value which selected while creating, same value must to render in while update